When are the pactl list values set up?
I've run into an odd situation.
I'm running pulseaudio in system mode.
I have a udev rule to run a script file when a usb device is removed. In this script I'm checking the aplay -l values and creating sinks.
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/home/admin/user/udev_script_log.txt"
echo "Script triggered by udev!" >> "$logfile"

# Clear all existing ALSA sinks
echo "Unloading existing ALSA sink modules..." >> "$logfile"
pactl list short modules | grep module-alsa-sink | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} pactl unload-module {} >> "$logfile" 2>&1

sleep 40


# Get the list of playback devices
aplay_output=$(aplay -l)
echo -e "\naplay -l values ------------\n$aplay_output" >> "$logfile"

# Parse the aplay output and load ALSA sink modules
echo "Loading ALSA sink modules..." >> "$logfile"
echo "$aplay_output" | while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^card\ ([0-9]+):\ .*,\ device\ ([0-9]+): ]]; then
    card=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    device=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    # Create a sink name based on card and device numbers
    sink_name="sink_${card}_${device}"

    # Load the ALSA sink module
    pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device="hw:$card,$device" sink_name="$sink_name" >> "$logfile" 2>&1
    echo "Sink $sink_name loaded." >> "$logfile"
  fi
done

pactl_values=$(pactl list sinks short)
echo "PACTL valuse ------------------ \n $pactl_values" >> "$logfile" 2>&1
echo "Update process complete." >> "$logfile"

Now it creates the sinks and prints the result of pactl list sinks short into the log file.
Thing is after this is done when I run pactl list sinks short in the terminal it looks like it's overwritten my sinks. It's updating the list after my rule is run.
So I added a delay and checked.
When I disconnected the usb, I kept checking the pactl list sinks short in the terminal. It was still listing the usb sink. It kept listing it. After the delay in my script, it no longer listed it. It looks like that process is being taken care of after my script is run.
When I check the logs, I'm printing both the aplay -l values and pactl list sinks short.
the aplay -l are correct and it creates the sinks correctly.
The pactl list sinks short values no longer lists the usb sink that was disconnected but it does list the newly created sinks.
It's only after the script runs that the terminal pactl list sinks short value cleans itself up again, thereby removing my newly created sinks.
What's going on?
